# Postgres continuous cumulative count

Tags: postgresql, sum, cumulative-sum

assuming table a with data

```
| id | timestamp   |  
|----|-------------|
| 1  | 12345677677 |  
| 2  | 12345677677 |  
| 3  | 12346600000 |
```

I nee a query which returns the cumulative count at a given point in time

```
| timestamp   | count| 
|-------------|------|
| 12345677677 | 2    | 
| 12346600000 | 3    |
```

so not the count(*) group by timestamp, but the count(*) group by timestamp + previous counts.

Thanks to @klin this works perfectly; However with the window function, I have a problem getting the distinct count(*) per day together with the cumulative sum in ONE query.

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date_created) AS date, 
       sum, 
       count(*) 
FROM   addon_user, 
       (SELECT DISTINCT ON(date_trunc('day', date_created)) 
       date_trunc('day', date_created), 
       count(*) 
       OVER ( 
         ORDER BY date_trunc('day', date_created)) AS sum 
        FROM   addon_user
) AS sub 

GROUP  BY date, 
          sum 
ORDER  BY date ASC
```

returns the Cartesian product:

```
timestamp  | count |sum
-------------+-------+---
12345677677 |     2|2
12345677677 |     2|5
12346600000 |     3|2
12346600000 |     3|5
```

while I need the data in form of

```
timestamp  | count |sum
-------------+-------+---
12345677677 |     2|2
12346600000 |     3|5
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `count()` as a window function with the `order by` clause. There is a nice feature in Postgres, `distinct on` to eliminate duplicate rows:

```
select distinct on(timestamp) timestamp, count(*) over (order by timestamp)
from my_table;

  timestamp  | count 
-------------+-------
 12345677677 |     2
 12346600000 |     3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I get the cartesian product with count and sum, see my edited question :)

Comment: @user39950: of course you get a cartesian product because you are not joining the `addon_user` table and your derived table (sub-query).

Comment: @user39950 - When you use two tables in the FROM clause without a join condition you always get a cartesian product. It's not clear to me why did you place the query in the FROM clause and where the column `sum` come from. Maybe you should ask a new question with full example input data and expected result.